# Minecraft Command Entity Spawning Problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to spawn an entity using an command but I can't. For example, I type in `/spawn pig` and nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong or is my computer messed up?

Comment: What problem are you having? You don't actually mention that.

Comment: I fixed the question.

Comment: /spawn isn't a command. Refer to http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands for the list of commands

Answer (score 8):

If you use Minecraft 1.7.2 or higher, you can use `/summon Pig ~ ~ ~` to summon a pig at your location. Replace the "~" with the x, y and z coordinates of the place you want it to appear.

Answer (score 2):

The command for spawning is **summon**, not spawn. Also, you are forgetting the capital letter.

For example: Instead of doing

```
/summon pig
```

you need to do

```
/summon Pig
```

Comment: As a programmer, I can tell you, the improper use of capitalisation is one of the most common mistakes - and the easiest to overlook. The resulting frustration will hopefully get you use to the idea a bit better, as it has done so with me.